# What is the correct code to convert to hex in below format?

Tags: php, hexdump

I am trying to send bengali text as sms using our local carrier api. But they don't support unicode (utf-8) text as post/get parameter. they replied this:

> For every Bengali alphabet there is standard HEXDUMP representation
>   which need to be inserted in message content part.
>
> Like below Bengali word is having below HEXDUMP representation
>
> বাংলাদেশ :    09AC09BE098209B209BE09A609C709B6

So, I tried following two code gathered from SO.

Code-1:

```
$strBN = 'বাংলাদেশ';
echo bin2hex($strBN);
//it reutrns this value "e0a6ace0a6bee0a682e0a6b2e0a6bee0a6a6e0a787e0a6b6"
```

Code-2:

```
$strBN = 'বাংলাদেশ';
echo fToHex($strBN);
function fToHex($string)
{
    $strHData = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($string); $i++)
    {
        $strHData .= str_pad(dechex(ord($string[$i])), 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
    }
    return $strHData;
}
//This also return same value as above "e0a6ace0a6bee0a682e0a6b2e0a6bee0a6a6e0a787e0a6b6"
```

So, my question is how I can convert that text/string to hexdump as my carrier expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hex dump that you are getting is UTF-8 format, which is a way to represent Unicode characters reliably in a 8-bit stream.

```
E0 A6 AC E0 A6 BE E0 A6 82 E0 A6 B2 E0 A6 BE E0 A6 A6 E0 A7 87 E0 A6 B6
```

The example on the other hand is a dump of the UTF-16 (or truncated 16-bit Unicode codepoint) values:

```
09AC 09BE 0982 09B2 09BE 09A6 09C7 09B6
```

In your case the solution is to convert to UTF-16 encoding:

```
echo bin2hex(mb_convert_encoding('বাংলাদেশ', 'UTF-16'));"
> 09ac09be098209b209be09a609c709b6
```

Note that using Unicode characters in code is unreliable, because the interpretation of the bytes in a string will depend on your system details / editor / compiler or interpreter settings etc.

Comment: i am very sorry to say sir, but when i tried your code it returns "**00e000a600ac00e000a600be00e000a6008200e000a600b200e000a600be00e000a600a600e000a7008700e000a600b6**" even bigger than earlier :(

Comment: That looks like there has been a double conversion on the way: that is a 16-bit word representation of UTF-8 encoded string. Try using your original Bengali string instead of what I copied there.

Comment: sir, i am getting very confused, when i tried on my system both my code (didn't copy paste yours on) and also copy paste your code, both return same value (the bigger one). but when i copy paste your code to online test system "http://phptester.net/" it works nice. what would be the issue at my end?

Comment: my bad sir, i get it figured out. on my development server (pc) php version is 5.4 and that's why it return that. when i test on my live server it returns correct value. btw... do you think it's a php bug on earlier versions?

Comment: The issue seems to be that before the string reaches your code, it is interpreted as UTF-8. You need to make sure that it is encoded as UTF-16 before `bin2hex`. See [mb_convert_encoding](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php)

Comment: Very good that you got it to work. The difference between versions may be what kind of input encoding they expect. As I added to my answer, storing Unicode strings in code is a risky business.

Comment: "storing Unicode strings in code is a risky business" wow? really? i always use/store unicode string in my code like in .js/.html/.php file. what risk it could be? and also what's the better way to store unicode strings in code file? sorry, i know it's not related to this post question. but still if you can help? :)

Comment: That is a matter of other discussions, but a short version: You must be sure that the strings and their encoding is preserved throughout the development lifecycle. Editors, interpreters, compilers, file formatters etc. may all change the way the characters are encoded. Since editors are very clever these days, those changes may go unnoticed. In order to make sure that you can *manage encodings from your code*, store the strings in an external file or use an i18n module.